# Calculate the overall circle enclosing multiple smaller circles

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have multiple smaller circles of a fixed radius that I am using to define a larger enclosing circle. So I'll need to find the x and y and radius of this new circle.

I am looking for **efficient over accuracy**, as past the third smaller circle any enclosed smaller circle will not be used to calculate a new circle. So if a new circle is introduce like the yellow one, the large blue circle could be used to define a new enclosing circle.

I am after a x,y and radius. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The center will be the circumcenter of the triangle determined by the three centers of the smaller circles.

Comment: So if I had the co-ordinates of those first three triangles, I could work out the center of the triangle from these ordinates and then how would I work out the radius of an enclosing circle?

Comment: The radius is the distance from the center of the circle to the center of any of the smaller circles plus the radius of one of the smaller circles.